# Primefaces 3.0 RC <p:messages> HTML formatting is not working

Tags: primefaces

I found out in primefaces.org that the version 3 Release Candidate of Primefaces is now ready for download, so I updated my website to use the new version. Unfortunately I the  tag doesn't interpret the html tags that I put on the FacesMessage. Is there a way to enable it?

like for example i put something like this in my backing bean:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, 
                    new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "","<b>Cannot load database driver.</b>"));
```

the bold HTML tag is being interpret as literals, it outputs the bold tag literally.

Comment: What tag doesn't work? Put some code!

Answer (score 0):

here a link to the primefaces forum about the same issue...
[escape="false" in p:messages](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=13761)

not sure you gonna like the suggested ways to solve it there...